# Print preview to PDF in safari layout fixes

Tags: pdf

When trying to print to PDF this page in Safari on Mac - https://theurbanwatch.com/fashion/seven-female-fashion-designers-to-celebrate-on-international-womens-day/, there are huge page breaks. How can this be fixed so the images flow from page to page, even if they are cut by pages?

And on the PDF of this page- http://www.ourtownny.com/news/from-cronuts-to-croissants-MA1772790 the logo repeats itself:

[image]

Is there any way to fix these? Like using the developer mode in Safari to adjust the CSS? Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different What macOS version are you on? Have you tried using File > Export As PDF...? Can you add a screenshot to your question so that we better understand what you mean?

Comment: Hey I'm on the latest macOS, here is the PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LR6BC70RBzKjynh_llb1UKuQyTll6UKj/view?usp=sharing. The logo repeating is the big problem, if that can be fixed somehow that would be so amazing. Thanks so much.